# Make select option selected on action

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a lsit of actions which can be selected one by one, or all or none by this `select` (each option comes as a button, I customized it):

```
<select ng-model="selectedActions">
            <option value="1">All</option>
            <option value="0">None</option>
</select>
```

My list:

```
<div ng-repeat="action in data.actions" >
<input type="checkbox"
   id="action_{{action.id}}"
   ng-model="data.actions[action.id].checked"
   ng-init="data.actions[action.id].checked=1"
   ng-true-value="1"
   ng-false-value="0">
</div>
```

If i load the view which contains the option list via URL (and even when I refresh the page), by default,the view is loaded with all options selected. Everything works fine, if i uncheck a single option, the "All" button becomes unsellected. If i manually check again all actions, the "All" button goes checked again (the same applies to the "None button"). The buttons are also working very well.

My problem is that when I acces this view via a link from a sidebar, and not via direct URL or refreshing the page), after the page loads with the "All" button checked and after I click the "None" button, if I click again the "All" button all the actions are selected, but the "All" button doesn t appear like selected. To make that happen, I must click on the "All" button again.

How can I get rid of that unnecesary one more click on the "All" button?

JS:

```
$scope.$watch('data.actions', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
            $scope.actions = [];
            for (var action in newVal){
                if(newVal[action]['checked'] === 1){
                    $scope.actions.push(action);
                }
            }
            if ($scope.actions.length == $scope.Schedule.getCurrentActionns().length){
                $scope.selectedActions = '1';
            } else if ($scope.actions.length == 0) {
                $scope.selectedActions = '0';
            } else {
                $scope.selectedActions = '';
            }
        }
    }, true);

$scope.$watch('selectedActions', function (newVal) {

            if (newVal) {
                for (var action in $scope.data.actions) {
                    if (newVal == 1) {
                        $scope.data.actions[action]['checked'] = 1;
                    }
                    if (newVal == 0) {
                        $scope.data.actions[action]['checked'] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
    });
```

Aditionally, when my page is loaded

```
if (!$scope.selectedActions){
          $scope.selectedActions = '1';
}
```

Comment: Instead of using watchers, use the [`ng-change` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) on the `<select>` and `<input>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using watchers, use the [`ng-change` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) on the `<select>` and `<input>` elements:

```
<select ng-model="selectedActions" ng-change=selectUpdate(selectedActions)>
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="0">None</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$scope.selectUpdate = function (newVal) {
    for (var action in $scope.data.actions) {
        if (newVal == 1) {
            $scope.data.actions[action]['checked'] = 1;
        }
        if (newVal == 0) {
            $scope.data.actions[action]['checked'] = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Similarly:

```
<div ng-repeat="action in data.actions" >
    <input type="checkbox"
       id="action_{{action.id}}"
       ng-model="data.actions[action.id].checked"
       ng-change="updateChecked(data.actions)"
       ng-init="data.actions[action.id].checked=1"
       ng-true-value="1"
       ng-false-value="0" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.updateChecked = function(newVal) {
    $scope.actions = [];
    for (var action in newVal){
        if(newVal[action]['checked'] === 1){
            $scope.actions.push(action);
        }
    }
    if ($scope.actions.length == $scope.Schedule.getCurrentActionns().length){
        $scope.selectedActions = '1';
    } else if ($scope.actions.length == 0) {
        $scope.selectedActions = '0';
    } else {
        $scope.selectedActions = '';
    }
}
```

Instead of dirty checking every digest cycle, the `ng-change` directive only invokes the function when the user changes the specific `<input>` or `<select>` element.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `ng-change` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)
- [AngularJS `<select>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)
- [AngularJS `<input>` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)